# Inline Visualforce page is displayed as a link in Community, any idea why? and how to remove the link behavior?

Tags: lightning-experience, napili, partner-communities, inline-visualforce, hyperlink

We have below simple example visualforce page (to be used as inline VF page for Opportunity).

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >
    This page doesn't have any content.
</apex:page>
```

This page is added to Opportunity page layout for Partner Community User.

When we view as partner community user, it appears as a link. Below screenshot shows how it appears on Opportunity page layout (in Partner community).

[image]

Because of this, it seems contents of inline pages are not accessible. Also when we click on this page, it goes to 'Invalid page' community page which is not intended at all.

Any idea how we can remove this link behavior? 
Appreciate any help on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this similar [Known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001Ch4QAE).

Followed it's workaround,

added below CSS to Community branding custom CSS.

```
.oneAlohaPage .mask { 
display: none; 
}
```

and that fixed the issue.